# Displaying Content Onclick without reloading/refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JavaScript and button to display a portion onclick and hide on re-clicking that portion.

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="block"
}
else{
e.style.display="none"
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

and the code for button is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('para2')" value="Technical Quiz" id="button">
```

and the content is:

```
<div id="para3" style="display:none; color:#FFF;">
Rules are Coming UP...
</div>
```

The main problem is when viewed in opera mini and uc browser, onclicking that button it reloads the page and displays the content. I don't want to reload the page. I just want to display the content without reloading the page.

Comment: Is your input element wrapped by a form element? I think in some cases the default onclick behavior for a input button is to submit the form, maybe try to remove the form element, just use this input

Comment: No, its not wrapped. I have just added `<div>...</div>` as a container.

Answer (score 3):

`return true` doesn't prevent the default action. the default action reloads the page. Therefore, you should `return false` to prevent the page reload.

```
return false;
```

Additional note. The page reload is likely due to a form being incorrectly submitted by said button.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the reload page is caused by the form submit. Are you sure the input is not wrapped by a  element?

you can try add `e.preventDefault()` in the toggleMe function which would block the default operation of the input button.